# Using Managed Identity on Azure SQL Managed Instance for Dacpac deployment in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to configure Azure Key Vault and setup Managed Identities for use in CI/CD pipeline for Azure Dev Ops.

I have looked around in MSDN documentation but I only specific links for use with Azure SQL and we are using Azure SQL Managed Instances.

Answer (score 1):

If I did not make any misunderstand, in fact, you want to use `Managed Identity` work with `Azure SQL Managed Instance`? If this, unfortunately to say, the Managed Identity could not work with Azure SQL Managed Instance. Please see this doc: [Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities). It list all of the Azure services name which support work with the `Managed identities` in great detail.

[image]

You can see for SQL database, it only support the integration with `Azure SQL` instead of `Azure SQL Managed Instance`. That's why you only see the doc link for the usage with `Azure SQL`.

Until now, the Azure SQL managed instance only support two [authentication method](https://teckadmin.wordpress.com/2019/06/23/sql-managed-instances/):

> **SQL Authentication:**
>
> This authentication method uses a username and password.
>
> **Azure Active Directory Authentication:**
>
> This authentication method uses identities managed by Azure Active
>   Directory and is supported for managed and integrated domains. Use
>   Active Directory authentication (integrated security) whenever
>   possible.

You can refer to this thread: [Managed Identity with Azure SQL Managed Instance?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23965). In this thread, out engineer provided some work around if you trying to configure the app with Managed Identity.

Comment: Thank you very much Merlin you have been a big help.

Comment: @SQLAstro, welcome!  You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works.